# First fgets() call being skipped during input?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm writing a program that can take computer specifics from the user in manual mode. However, I've run into a bit of a problem.

In this code:

```
    char choice = getc(stdin);

    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
    {
        config_file = fopen(config_file_loc, "w");

        printf("%s", "Please enter the name of your distribution/OS: ");
        fgets(distro_str, MAX_STRLEN, stdin);
        fputs(distro_str, config_file);
        fputs("\n", config_file);

        printf("%s", "Please enter your architecture: ");
        fgets(arch_str, MAX_STRLEN, stdin);
        fputs(arch_str, config_file);
        fputs("\n", config_file);

        fclose(config_file);
    }
```

During runtime, the input jumps right from "Please enter the name of your distribution/OS:" to "Please enter your architecture:", leaving distro_str blank.

I've tried flushing stdin and stdout, but those haven't worked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getc(stdin)` to get the "choice" character, it reads exactly one character from the input buffer.  If the user entered "y" followed by a newline, then the newline will remain in the input buffer, and the subsequent `fgets()` call will read that - an empty line - and return immediately.

If you wish all input to be line-oriented, then you should call `fgets()` each time, including when reading the "choice" value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either. It still skips the (now second) fgets() call.

Comment: @CommanderWorf: How large is the buffer that you're passing to the first `fgets()` call? It needs to be larger than 2, because any characters that `fgets()` does not have room to read will be left in the input buffer, perpetuating the problem.

Comment: I've changed the buffer to three characters wide, which seems to have fixed it. However, the result is a rather ugly string comparison where I check for the newline as well as "y" or "Y".

Comment: You should probably make the buffer large enough to handle the longest line you expect a user to enter, otherwise you'll have the same problem if they enter a longer string at the "choice" prompt.  If you want to ensure you've read the entire line, you need to check that the last character in the string that was read is a '`\n`', and if not, call `fgets()` again until it is.  You don't need to use a string comparison if you just want to compare the first character - you can compare `choice_str[0] == 'y' || choice_str[0] == 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

`getc` will return the character, but then new line character is still in the `stdin` buffer, so your first call to `fgets` gets a line with just a new line character.

Comment: I've tried flushing stdin after the fgetc() call with `fflush(stdin)`, but this doesn't fix the problem. Is there any other way to remove trailing data in stdin?

Comment: @CommanderWorf `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. Try using `fgets` and `sscanf` to get `'choice'`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware. How do I get rid of the newline then?