# fgets() not working in a function

Tags: c, string, char, stdin, fgets

I am writing a program which uses fgets() to scan a 3 Char long string as an Airport code for Departure and arrival. When I write the statement outside its method  (in the main) it works fine however inside it does not wait for input and leaves the variables blank.

```
void newFlight ()
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("============= CREATE A NEW FLIGHT ============= \n");
        printf("Type 0 at any point to exit to main menu. \n");
        printf("\n");

        printf("EnterFlight ID (0 to cancel) : ");
        scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID);

        char codeA [4];
        printf ("Enter Destination (Airport Code): ");
        fgets(codeA, 3, stdin);
        strcpy(codeA, flyList[curFly].arrive);
        printf("%s   %s \n", codeA, flyList[curFly].arrive);  //TEST

        printf("Enter Place Of Departure: ");
        char codeD[4];
        scanf("%s", codeD);
        strcpy(codeD, flyList[curFly].depart);
        printf("%s   %s \n", codeD, flyList[curFly].depart);  //TEST

        printf("Enter Date Of Departure (DD MM YYYY): ");
        scanf("%hd %hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.day, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.month, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.year);

        printf("Enter Time Of Departure (HH MM)in 24Hr Format: ");
        scanf("%hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.hour, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.minute);       

        curFly++;
    }
```

Comment: I added a fflush(stdin); now it waits for input but does not take it...

Comment: scanf remain newline. and rewrite by next `strcpy(codeA, flyList[curFly].depart);`

Comment: @Barmar I checked this out, I do not think it is the same thing as he had a problem with iterations, my problem is with the actual scanning of the string

Comment: The `%d` left the newline in the input buffer for the next input operation; that input operation was `fgets()` which looks for material up to the next newline.  The first character in the input is newline; that's the only character `fgets()` reads.  It is a standard problem and @Barmar identified one of many plausible duplicates.

Comment: You should also note that airport codes are 3 characters long, so you need to read into a buffer of at least 4 bytes; you have to specify enough space for the terminating null byte too.  Further, if you have a 3-character airport code read correctly, that will again leave the newline behind.  Fortunately, the `%s` conversion specification skips leading white space, so you won't be affected by that. (Incidentally, another question in this category: [First `fgets()` call being skipped during input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819134/first-fgets-call-being-skipped-during-input).)

Comment: Simply refrain form using members of the `scanf()`-clan, at least when trying to scan in such fuzzy thing as human output ... err ;-)

Comment: And, finally from me (for now), you don't check any of the input operations so you have no idea whether `fgets()` is working or not.  You _must_ check _every_ input operation to make sure it worked correctly.  You're simply headed for disaster if you don't.

Comment: agein check [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

Comment: Would be useful to show your `flyList` type.

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin)`; it has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing `fgets()` with `scanf()` is problematic.

`fgets()` consumes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`\n`).
`scanf("%d", ...` sees the `\n`, which stops the `%d` conversion, and puts `\n` back into `stdin` for the *next* IO operation - which happend to be OP's `fgets()` which returns promptly with a short string.

Also need to check `scanf()` results. specifying a width with `"%s` is good, like `"%3s`.

Quick solution: only using `scanf()`

```
 //  scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID);
if (1 != scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID)) handle_error();
 ...
char codeA [4];
// fgets(codeA, 3, stdin);
if (1 != scanf("%3s", codeA) handle_error();
...
// Likely backwards
// strcpy(codeA, flyList[curFly].arrive);
strcpy(flyList[curFly].arrive, codeA);
...
char codeD[4];
// scanf("%3s", codeD);
if (1 != scanf("%3s", codeD)) handle_error();
...
// scanf("%hd %hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.day, &flyList ...
if (3 != scanf("%hd %hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.day, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.month, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.year)) handle_error();
...
// scanf("%hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.hour, &flyList ...
if (2 != scanf("%hd %hd", &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.hour, &flyList[curFly].timeOfDep.minute)) handle_error();
```

Better solution: use `fgets()/sscanf()`

```
 //  scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID);
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID)) handle_parse_error();
... 
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%3s", flyList[curFly].arrive) handle_parse_error();
...
etc.
```

BTW: `scanf()` format `"%hd %hd"` and `"%hd%hd"` do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you :D this works perfectly
I think i will use the basic solution as this is my first assignment in C. Would you mind explaining the 'if (1 != scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID)) handle_error(); ' which is used for scanning strings
thanks again

Comment: The `%d` tells `scanf()` to look for an `int`.  If successful, `scanf()` returns 1 as 1 specifier was found.  If 0 (no `int` found) or `EOF` (end-of-file or IO error), the function `handle_error()` is executed.  `handle_error()` is just a dummy name for you code on how you would handle illegal input - which I find easier in the 2nd solution.

Comment: This might be late.. But can you also suggest a way to get around if there is an overflow and next fgets is not automatically. I mean if the input string is more than the size of char array, next char array will be assigned automatically. One solution I can think of is using fseek and moving stdin pointer to end

Comment: @VidorVistrom Are you looking for something line [getline()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)?

Comment: @chux probably. getline does not appear in c headers always. Though its a c++ thing but yes something like that. It would be great if you could suggest an overflow solution using fgets itself.

Comment: @VidorVistrom `getline()` is not part of the standard C library, yet source code readily findable.  What you want cannot be done with a single functions call from that library.  `fgets()` _can_ work as a building block, but your request lacks details and there are numerous issues (memory management, input null character handling, how to convey size read, error indication,  size limit to prevent hackers, etc.)   to the _general_ problem you pose.  Suggest you search SO and if needed, create sample code, detailing what you can and post a question.

Answer (score 1):

the problem isn't coming from `fgets` but rather from `scanf` because when this line is executed 
`scanf("%d", &flyList[curFly].flightID);`
and after you hit enter the newline charactere stays in the buffer so when you call `fgets` it is immediately given to it so it acts as if you hit Enter and moves on . one simple way to prevent this from happening is to put a `getchar` after every `scanf` so that it receives the newline character instead